# django: unable to redirect to another view in django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm trying to click on a button in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/electronics/switch/` to call `getCommodityCommentDetail` to do something, and then redirect to another page `commodityInfoPage`.

What puzzles me is that the page always shows the same content in the initial page, although the url has changed e.g. to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/comments/1/`.

After testing, I found that the `commodityInfoPage` in views.py isn't called. I have searched long time for solutions, but all of them failed. So how can I fix it?

urls.py:

```
app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    # eg:127.0.0.1:8000/main/
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('getCommodityInfo/', views.getCommodityInfo, name = 'getCommodityInfo'),
    path('getCommodityCommentDetail/', views.getCommodityCommentDetail, name="getCommodityCommentDetail"),
    path('<str:category>/<str:searchKey>/',views.commodityInfoPage, name = 'commodityInfoPage'),
    path('comments/<str:commodityId>/', views.commodityCommentPage,name = 'commodityCommentPage'),
]
```

view.py:

```
def getCommodityCommentDetail(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        commodityId = request.POST.get("commodityId")
        # scrapy module is waiting implementation

        #
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:commodityInfoPage',args=(commodityId)))

def commodityCommentPage(request, commodityId):
    print("enter commodityCommentPage")
    commentList = JDCommentDetail.objects.all()
    context = {'commentList':commentList}
    return render(request,'main/commodityCommentPage.html',context)
```

templates:

```
<form action="{% url 'main:getCommodityCommentDetail'%}" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input class="hidden" value="{{commodity.id}}" name="commodityId">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >review</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that `args` should be a tuple or a list, i.e. `args=(commodityId,)`.

Comment: I have check the source code, but I can't understand why args must be tuple or list.Could you tell me why?[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/urls/base/#reverse)

Comment: First, see [examples in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/url) - they use a list. It should be a list or a tuple because there can be more than one arg. Your code is probably working for you at the moment because `commodityId` is a single character string, e.g. `"1"`. If you test with `args=("15")`, [I think it will be treated](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/base.py#L90) the sane way as `args=["1", "5"]` (since strings are iterable), and you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `comments/1/` is matched by the `commodityInfoPage` URL pattern.

```
path('<str:category>/<str:searchKey>/',views.commodityInfoPage, name='commodityInfoPage'),
```

You can fix this problem by changing the URL patterns so that they don't clash, or by moving the `commodityCommentPage` URL pattern above the `commodityInfoPage` one.

```
path('comments/<str:commodityId>/', views.commodityCommentPage, name='commodityCommentPage'),
path('<str:category>/<str:searchKey>/', views.commodityInfoPage, name='commodityInfoPage'),
```

Note that if you re-order the patterns, you won't be able to view `commodityInfoPage` if the category is 'comments'.

Comment: Thanks!!! I have changed the path to the below pattern, and it works.
`path('commodityInfo/<str:category>/<str:searchKey>/',views.commodityInfoPage, name = 'commodityInfoPage'),`